# Oracle - Problem with creating a Trigger which check number of employees in department

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I need to create a Trigger in oracle. Trigger has to check if the number of employees in department is between 1 and 10. I'm wondering about this for 2 days and still I can not find a solution.

I wrote something like this, but I got an error: "ORA-04091: table is mutating"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER deptEmp
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
emp_counts NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO emp_counts FROM emp WHERE emp.deptno = :NEW.deptno;
IF emp_counts > 10 OR emp_counts = 0 THEN
raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not correct number of employees in dept'):
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: You can't query the table you are changing in `before` trigger. Try using `AFTER` instead.

Comment: @JorgeCampos same problem with `AFTER`.

Comment: Check this thread and see if it helps: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/235499/42478

Comment: Not related to the error, but won't your logic prevent you adding the first employee to a new department, as the count for that will initially be zero? And add an 11th employee, but not a 12th? (If it worked...)

Comment: Also, your code works if you do individual `insert ... values ...` (and there is already one empoyee for the department); but will throw ORA-04091 if you do `insert ... select ...`. How are you performing your insert(s)?

Answer (score 1):

The count for a first employee of any department is 0, so you can't exclude it from being inserted.

But you need the count after inserting , deleting or updating, so you should add a correcting variable, that accounts for that,

And MT0 explained that is better to use `COALESCE (:NEw.deptno,:OLD.deptno)` in case `:New.deptno` is NULL, like when you delete the employee

```
CREATE tABLe emp (deptno int)
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER deptEmp
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
emp_counts int;
correcting_counts int;
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN 
      correcting_counts := 1;
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    correcting_counts := -1;
  ELSE
    correcting_counts := 0;
  END IF;
    SELECT (COUNT(*) + correcting_counts) INTO emp_counts FROM emp WHERE emp.deptno = COALESCE(:NEW.deptno, :OLD.deptno);
    IF emp_counts > 10 OR  emp_counts <= 0 THEN
       raise_application_error(-20000,'Not correct number of employees in dept');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

```
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;
```

```
INSERT INTO emp VALUES(1)
```

```
1 rows affected
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f8m3qcTO)

Comment: When `DELETING` the `:NEW.deptno` will be `NULL`. You could use `COALESCE(:NEW.deptno, :OLD.deptno)`.

Comment: It's also querying the target table, so it will still get ORA-04091 in the same circumstances the OP's version would (i.e. `insert ... select ...`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER deptEmp
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON emp
DECLARE
  v_invalid PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
  INTO   v_invalid
  FROM   (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   departments d
           LEFT OUTER JOIN emp e
           ON (e.deptno = d.deptno)
    GROUP BY d.deptno
    HAVING COUNT(e.deptno) < 1
    OR     COUNT(e.deptno) > 10
  )
  WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;

  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
    -20000,
    'Must be between 1 and 10 employees in a department'
  );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

Then, if you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE departments (deptno int PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE emp (deptno REFERENCES departments (deptno) );
```

You can create departments and employees:

```sql
INSERT INTO departments (deptno) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO emp (deptno) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO departments (deptno) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO emp (deptno) VALUES (2);
```

If you try to insert too many employees:

```sql
INSERT INTO emp (deptno)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12;
```

Then it fails with:

> ```
> ORA-20000: Must be between 1 and 10 employees in a department
> ```

Similarly, it will fail if you try to `DELETE` or `UPDATE` and leave it in an invalid state.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6fd36c/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a statement level trigger such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER deptEmp
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON emp
DECLARE
  emp_counts_min INT;
  emp_counts_max INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT MIN(COUNT(*)), MAX(COUNT(*))
    INTO emp_counts_min, emp_counts_max
    FROM emp 
   GROUP BY deptno; -- overlaps each dept which is provided next to WHERE within the current case   
   
 IF (emp_counts_min NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 10) OR (emp_counts_max NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 10) THEN
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Not correct number of employees in dept'):
 END IF;
END;
/
```

rather than a row-level trigger in order to prevent table mutating error.